# GET Web API Method returns method not allowed

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, api-design

I am developing web api project that will be mediator between our website and third party service and my website need to call my api where my api will adapt the request in the way third party service is expecting it, however I am getting method not allowed on my get method and I am kinda stuck. I've tried enabling CORS, but it still doesn't help , I've checked if our website is really calling with GET verb and it does, but my Web API is still returning:

> The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

This is the code of the method that our website is calling:

```
public IHttpActionResult CommitReserve()
{
    var request = this.Request;
    this.Logger.InfoFormat("CommitReserve: {0}", request.RequestUri);

    try
    {
        var customerID = request.GetRequestParameter<string>("cust_id");
        var reserveID = request.GetRequestParameter<int>("reserve_id");
        this.Logger.InfoFormat("CommitReserve: ReserveId: {0}, CustID: {1}", reserveID, customerID);

        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.AppendLine("error_code=" + 0);
        sb.AppendLine("error_message=");
        sb.AppendLine("trx_id=" + reserveID);
        sb.Append("balance=" + 0);

        response.Content = new StringContent(sb.ToString());
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");

        return this.ResponseMessage(response);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
        this.Logger.ErrorFormat("CommitReserve: {0}" + ex);
        return this.BadRequest(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

and this is how I enabled CORS:

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
```

I know its bad the way I did it but it is just for test t osee if this is really the problem , turns out it is not.

This is the request that I am sending with postman and it fails:

```
GET http://localhost:60747/api/Reserve/CommitReserve?cust_id=32569_5001&reserve_id=62150259&SportTypeID=sport HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:60747
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Postman-Token: 8f26fb31-d59d-78c8-2399-3b46c4beeff5
Cache-Control: no-cache
cust_id: 32569_5001
reserve_id: 62148599
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,    like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
amount: 2
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.6
```

So I ran out of options here..

**EDITS **

WebApiConfig.cs as requested:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: Make sure `api/reserve` leads to the controller. Can you post your `WebApiConfig.cs` file? and Logger trace if u have it.

Comment: I edited my question , but I dont think routing is the problem..

Comment: `CommitReserve` is the only method you have? Make sure any other method doesn't conflict with this method's route.

Comment: I found the answer guys I will answer it , stay tuned.

Comment: I would like to know why I got downvoted , I really love the feedback as to me it feels like I am moving forward..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue and the bug was rather interesting to me.

Problem was that this method `CommitReserve` was coming from an interface and apparently(sorry, for not mentioning it, but I thought it was not relevant, silly me!) attributes are not inherited(routing was working because of the name of the method), once applied to interface methods, in the implementing class.

I fixed this with making `IReserveController` an abstract class.

However I looked upon the IL code of method `CommitReserve` once like abstract method of an abstract class and once like interface method and I saw no significant difference which bugs me , because now I want to know what is responsible for this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you returning JSON? If so, you need to explicitly allow GET:

```
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: If your answer has to start with a question, it's probably better off as a comment.

Comment: I edited my question, which method you are asking if it returns JSON ? I am getting confused , api method is not executed at all because it is forbidden(Not allowed) , or I am mistaken?

Comment: I was asking if you are returning JSON from your action,  it wasn't clear from the answer. Now I see you aren't, so please disregard my answer.

Comment: Added the request I am making also for more clarifications

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you need to define the "api/Reserve" prefix. You can do so by adding a Route attribute to the controller class with this string, or modify the Route attribute in the method to "api/reserve/CommitReserve".

Comment: This is already added to controller, anyway if it was not then it would return 404 if I am not mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting this error in your **GetRequestParameter**. So you need to access your query string like this,

```
var _req = Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
string customerID = _req.FirstOrDefault(ma => string.Compare(ma.Key, "cust_id") == 0).Value;
string reserveID = _req.FirstOrDefault(ma => string.Compare(ma.Key, "reserve_id") == 0).Value;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: But you have mention "I've checked if our website is really calling with GET verb and it does, but my Web API is still returning:405"

Comment: Yes, my website solution was making GET requests , but my API was blocking them because `CommitReserve` was by default POST only , see my answer and you will see what I mean